# python os.path.exists not working from localhost

Tags: php, python

I am running a python script from php file. In the python script i have to check a folder existing or not. The Folder from a mount location. If i do the check for os.path.exists is not working. Below is my sample code.

```
mount_smbfs //user1:1234@system1/Apps/PublishAssets ~/z
```

in python i am checking in such a way that .

```
os.path.exists('/Volumes/PublishAssets')
```

i am running php from local host.

```
http://localhost/~user1/Apps/index.php
```

i am always getting folder not existing. But physically am able to see the folder and folder contents.

Please help me to get the proper path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely you're mounting it at `~/z`, not `/Volumes/`, so you should be checking there?

Comment: What should i give `os.path.exists('/z/PublishAssets')` is it correct ?

Comment: Have a look in your file system. Once you know the folder path in there you just give the same thing to the python function. Probably something like `os.path.exists('/Users/your_account/z')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways (pick just one though):

Change mount point to `/Volumes/PublishAssets`

### **OR** (XOR)

Change path specified in Python:

```
# os.path.exists('/Volumes/PublishAssets')
# replace with
os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/z'))
```

**Make sure the user running the script has permissions to the mounted filesystem**

To mount with permissions:

```
mount_smbfs -f0777 -d0777 //user:pass@host/folder /target
```

Comment: Thanks Sharabni, I used `os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/z'))`, still not working. when i do print the path i am getting `/Library/WebServer/z` in my browser. I used the command as `print os.path.expanduser('~/z')`. Note : if i run the command from terminal.app it is working.

Comment: @RameshRC Where exactly is your directory mounted? Go to the directory and check the output of `pwd`. If you're still having trouble post it here.

Comment: No luck Sharabani, i will explain the steps what i done, Please correct me if am wrong. 1) Created a folder in /Users/user1/z . 2) Mounted the share folder (`mount_smbfs //user1:1234@system1/Apps/PublishAssets ~/z`). 3) Checking if folder exists or not `os.path.exists('/Users/user1/z')` Not working.

Comment: @Sharabani , May be something do with localhost ? Because i am executing python script from .php file `http://localhost/~user1/Apps/index.php` .

Comment: @RameshRC what user is running the script? what user is running mount_smbfs? what does mount_smbfs do (where does it mount `~/z`)? `z` is relative to the user, so you may want to see what user is running what script.

Comment: user1 is the user does everything. `z` is located to under user1

Comment: If you're using a `php` file I'd suppose it's used by someone accessing a website, and executed by a user like `apache` or something. Are you **sure** this is the user executing the script?

Comment: Yes, This system is creating for to do automate the build system. So user1 is the will running `Apache` server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66981/discussion-between-reut-sharabani-and-ramesh-r-c).